# How do I make link act like a view or a view look like a link?

Tags: views, routes, navigation

Good morning!

I want to create a link that displays a node, the most recently created for example. What is the best way to do that in Drupal?

I have a menu link that does what I want with: 
moneymap/Pro/EURUSD/Day?sort_by=field_map_id_value&sort_order=DESC
but I don't know how that works or how to make that work in an HTML link.

I've made a few views but still a beginner? How should I proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Anil for your time and help. I'm a little confused about the last part. I can create the view. But how do I get that view into my currently static link:
<a href="/rmmdev/randymreflections/2141"></a>
Thank you for any clarification!

Answer (score 0):

- Easiest way to achieve above is using Views
- Create a new view with block view

[image]

- Sort Content by Post Date
- Select fields as Content Display and show only one item
- Enable the block by Navigating to blocks list page "admin/structure/block"

Please find the view code which you can simply import using "admin/structure/views/import"

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'latest_node';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Latest Node';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Latest Node';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block');
```